# Implementing a new environment for Log Entry Journal

Tags: environments

I am trying to define a new environment to create a log journal.  In the left margin I wish the display the entry date.  Each entry should be separated from the entry above via blank line and have a bold log-entry title and all paragraphs within in the log entry should not be indented.

I have tried with the code below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\vspace{\parskip}\reversemarginpar\marginnote{#1}\textbf{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{loggentry}{2016-Apr-20} {Entry Title NO INDENT}
Text for the entry starting with NO Indent on new line

\end{loggentry}
\end{document}
```

In my output the "heading" and each new paragraph are still being indented and the first line of text is continued on the heading line after the heading and my vertical skip to get separator line is not working.

How do I resolve these issues?

Stuart

Comment: A tip: Use a macro wrapper for the date formatting, say `\displaymydate{2016}{04}{20}` which is valid for all cases, but displays the date according to your design, i.e. ISO date, or American/English style etc.

Comment: Your `\newenvironment` definition is missing the end code brace pair `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

The paragraph indent is controlled by `\parindent`, setting this to `0em` will remove the indent.

Leaving an empty line after `\textbf{#2}` will place the first real content line in a new line (paragraph) then.

The space between the title line and the content can be changed with `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip`, for example.

I used `\smallskip` in the environment's end code section for better impression (consecutive `logentry` environments were placed too near to each other, in my point of view!)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]{%
  \parindent=0em%

  \reversemarginpar\marginnote{#1}%
  \textbf{#2}

}{\smallskip}


\newenvironment{logentry}[2]{%
  \parindent=0em%

  \reversemarginpar\marginnote{#1}%
  \textbf{#2}
  \medskip

}{\smallskip}


\begin{document}
\begin{loggentry}{2016-Apr-20}{Entry Title NO INDENT}
Text for the entry starting with NO Indent on new line
\end{loggentry}

\begin{logentry}{2016-Apr-20}{Entry Title NO INDENT}
Text for the entry starting with NO Indent on new line
\end{logentry}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes almost.  How can I get a blank line between enteries.  I uncommented the \vspace but this did not appear to work.

Comment: @StuartNorris: A blank line between the bold title line and the log entry?

Comment: @StuartNorris: See the update please

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the detailed explanation also.

Comment: @StuartNorris: You're welcome. Please consider to make yourself a registered user ;-)